# Return only one subset of a given number list that sums to a target value

Tags: c#, subset-sum

I was hoping someone could assist with an issue I'm having with a subset sum problem.  I took the below code from another thread.  What I'd like to do, ideally, is have a function that returns the first array that meets this condition: " if (s == target && partial.ToArray().Length == 7)".
Is that possible with the code I'm using below?  In other words, I don't want ALL of the combinations, just the first one that meets that condition.  I've tried a few things, but I'm not experienced enough at C# to really understand how to break out of the recursion or return the array to a calling function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 2, 6, 6, 5, 8, 1, 3, 3, 9, 3, 6, 1, 3, 9, 1, 7, 8, 6, 8, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 8, 4, 5, 4, 6, 10, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 2, 4 };
        int target = 27;
        sum_up(numbers, target);
    }

    private static void sum_up(List<int> numbers, int target)
    {
        sum_up_recursive(numbers, target, new List<int>());
    }

    private static void sum_up_recursive(List<int> numbers, int target, List<int> partial)
    {
        int s = 0;
        foreach (int x in partial) s += x;

        if (s == target && partial.ToArray().Length == 7)
            Console.WriteLine("sum(" + string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()) + ")=" + target);

        if (s >= target)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            List<int> remaining = new List<int>();
            int n = numbers[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Count; j++) remaining.Add(numbers[j]);

            List<int> partial_rec = new List<int>(partial);
            partial_rec.Add(n);
            sum_up_recursive(remaining, target, partial_rec);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You could make `sum_up_recursive` return `true` when if finds a solution, and `false` when it does not. Then you can exit the loop when the return value (of the recursive call) is `true`.

Comment: So do I understand this correctly? You want to find the first 7 consecutive numbers in your list that add up to the target number?

Comment: @Meloviz That's pretty much the idea, but it being the first 7 consecutive is not that important to me.  My vision is that I'll have a list of seven numbers which I'll then remove from the original array and then run again until all of the numbers have been allocated.  Proving to be quite tricky though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are easier ways of doing this, but to use your code, I believe this is one way you could do it:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<int> numbers = new List<int>
    { 
        2, 6, 6, 5, 8, 1, 3, 3, 9, 3, 6, 1, 3, 9, 1, 7, 8, 6, 8, 1, 1,
        4, 4, 2, 8, 4, 5, 4, 6, 10, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 2, 4 
    };
    int target = 27;
    sum_up(numbers, target);
}

private static void sum_up(List<int> numbers, int target)
{
    sum_up_recursive(numbers, target, new List<int>(), 0);
}

private static void sum_up_recursive
    (List<int> numbers, int target, List<int> @partial, int index)
{
    int s = @partial.Sum();

    if (s >= target && @partial.Count == 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sum(" + string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()) + ")=" + target);
    }
    else if (s < target)
    {
        if( index + 7 > numbers.Count )
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            List<int> partial_rec = numbers.GetRange(index, index + 7);
            sum_up_recursive(numbers, target, partial_rec, ++index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thank you.  I just need to figure out how I can return this value to the original function.

Comment: @Majobber, If you want to return the list from `sum_up_recursive`, just change its return value from `void` to `List<int>` and replace the `Console.WriteLine(...)` with `return numbers.GetRange(index, index + 7)`. Also put a `return` before the call to `sum_up_recursive` at the end of itself.